# How to simulate inbuilt microphone on Android?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, microphone, simulate

I am developing an Android app which have to use both the smartphone's inbuilt mic and a bluetooth headset mic. I want to add a radio button in my app, so that users can freely choose to use either the inbuilt mic or the bluetooth headset mic.

When a user choose bluetooth headset mic, the bluetooth headset mic should simulate the inbuilt mic, that is, the bluetooth headset mic exactly replaces the inbuilt mic.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my own question!

The answer is [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

After my bluetooth headset has connected to my smart phone. There is just two steps to do:

Step one:

```
mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
```

Step two:

```
mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
```

Then my headset bluetooth's mic is working!